# About surjectivity of a certain map.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\psi$ be a function from $O(2n)$ to $M(2n,R)$. $\psi(S)$ where $S\in O(2n)$ is defined as $SQS^{-1}$. $Q$ is a 2nx2n matrix that has blocks
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
on its diagonal. Now I want to show that this image lands precisely in the set of real skew-symmetric matrices with eigenvalues +-i.
It is possible that this can be done by brute force but I wanted to know if there is a clever way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\pm i$ are the only eigenvalues then  $Q^2=-I.$ If additionally  $Q$ is skew-symmetric then $Q^tQ=I.$ Perhaps this helps    finding $n$ two-dimensional invariant subspaces for $Q.$ For example for $0\neq v\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ the subspace spanned by $v$ and $Qv$ is two-dimensional and invariant.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your comment. Q is a matrix with certain blocks on its diagonal defined above. If by Q you mean a real skew-symmetric matrix with +-i eigenvalues. In addition could you clarify what we do once we construct those n two-dimensional invariant subspaces. I couldn't connect the two. I am super rusty with linear algebra.

Comment: Sorry, I had in mind any skew-symmetric matrix $P$ with eigenvalues $\pm i.$ Such matrix satisfies $P^2=-I$ and $P^tP=I.$ We have to show that there exists na orthogonal matrix  $S$ such that $SQS^{-1}=P.$ I suggest decomposing the space into $n$   two dimensional invariant subspaces for $P.$

Comment: If you like I can try to write down a solution as elementary as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a skew-symmetric matrix with all eigenvalues $\pm i.$ Since $P^t=-P,$ then $P$ is a normal matrix, i.e. $P^tP=PP^t.$ Hence, by a general theorem, it is similar   to a diagonal matrix $D$ (over complex field) with numbers $\pm i$ on the main diagonal (similarity means that $P=UDU^{-1}$ for an invertible matrix $U).$ Therefore $$P^2=-I,\qquad P^tP=-P^2=I.$$

Fix $v_1\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with $\|v_1\|=1.$  Let $w_1=Pv_1.$ Then $$\|w_1\|^2=\langle Pv_1,Pv_1\rangle =\langle P^tPv_1,v_1\rangle =1.$$
Moreover the vectors $v_1$ and $w_1$ are orthogonal to each other as
$$\langle v_1,w_1\rangle =\langle v_1,Pv_1\rangle
=\langle P^tv_1,v_1\rangle =-\langle Pv_1,v_1\rangle =-\langle w_1,v_1\rangle.$$
Observe that $Pw_1=P^2v_1=-v_1.$ Hence the matrix $P$ restricted to $V_1={\rm span}\,\{w_1,v_1\},$ with respect to the basis $w_1,\,v_1,$ is of the form
\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \end{equation}
Consider the orthogonal complement $V_1^\perp.$ This space is invariant under the action of $P$ (in general it follows from the fact that $P$ and $P^t$ commute). Indeed, let $u\perp w_1,\, v_1.$ Then
$$\langle Pu, \alpha w_1+\beta v_1\rangle=
\langle u, -P(\alpha w_1+\beta v_1)\rangle=
\alpha \langle u,v_1\rangle -\beta\langle u,w_1\rangle=0.$$
Now we consider the matrix $P$ restricted to $V_1^\perp.$ We choose a unit vector $v_2\in V_1^\perp$ and define $w_2=Pv_2.$ As before we define $V_2={\rm span}\,\{w_2,v_2\}$ and observe that the matrix $P$ restricted to $V_2$ with respect to orthonormal vectors $w_2,\, v_2$ is of the form (1).  As before the space $(V_1+V_2)^\perp$ is invariant under the action of $P.$

We continue that procedure until we get the system of $2n$  orthonormal vectors $\{w_k,v_k\}_{k=1}^n. $ By construction the matrix $P,$ with respect to that system, is equal $Q.$ Let $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^{2n}$ denote the standard orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}.$ Then the linear mapping
$S$ defined by
$$Se_{2k-1}=w_k,\qquad Se_{2k}=v_k,\quad k=1,2,\ldots, n,$$
belongs to $O(\mathbb{R}^{2n}),$ as it maps orthonormal system into another orthonormal system. Moreover  $SQS^{-1}=P.$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Don't mind if I take some time to understand it. I'll upvote it as soon as I fully understand it.

Comment: No problem. If you need  additional explanations I can modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think I almost got it. Just need a few clarifications.                                                        
1) I am not sure how $P^2 = UD^2U^{-1}$ is $-I$ and 2) Given Q and an orthogonal matrix S how can we say that $SQS^{-1}$ is skew-symmetric with +-i eigenvalues.

Comment: I decided to put explanations in the comment section, as they deal with basic properties of matrices.   1) As $D$ is diagonal with entries $\pm i$ on the main diagonal, then $D^2=-I.$ Hence $P^2=U(-I)U^{-1}=-I.$    2) It is a general fact that the eigenvalues of $Q$ and $SQS^{-1}$ are equal for any invertible matrix $S.$ If in addition $S$ is orthogonal, i.e. $S^t=S^{-1}.$ we get  $SQS^{-1}=SQS^t.$ Next $(SQS^t)^t=SQ^tS^t=-SQS^t.$ Hence $SQS^{-1}$ is skew-symmetric.  I have used a general fact that $(AB)^t=B^tA^t.$

Comment: Thanks again looks like these were pretty obvious.